# My transaction finally received 0 token

Tags: 0x

This is not the first time this happened to me. I also added the buyAmount parameter to judge, and still received 0 tokens. Is there any way to prevent it from happening again? Thank you
my txid:
https://bscscan.com/tx/0x4e7b6894eb88c3477ec121221656772040e40696a859884dcc580e1b41ea4e37

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the minimum buy amount was set to `0`. Did you make a swap request with `slippagePercentage=1`? This effectively removes any slippage protection during execution. What did the quote response say how much BUSD you would get back?

Comment: I have added "slippagePercentage" this parameter, and I see that the same block has not been attacked by sandwiches, so I don’t understand why this happens.

Comment: It seems like a bad DODO pool. Had you set `slippagePercentage` to `<1` the trade would have reverted and you would have been protected. `slippagePercentage=1` is extremely dangerous.